# Batch processing and get first key from StackExcahnge.Redis c#

Tags: c#, redis, key, batch-processing, stackexchange.redis

I am currently implementing Redis implementation using StackExchange.Redis for our c# project. I have couple of questions around it-

1. We need  to send multiple values to Redis. I am planning to use ExecuteAsync() for my batch processing. Wondering if I use CreateBatch() method will it be better.?

   ```
    var transaction = _database.CreateTransaction();
    tasks.Add(transaction.StringSetAsync(new RedisKey(key), new 
              RedisValue(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.Value)), 
                new TimeSpan(absoluteExpiration.Value.Ticks)));
    transaction.ExecuteAsync()
   ```
2. We need to fetch first single key from Redis. We plan to store our Key in below way

   [G:A][SG:B][Key:HL9703182569]

   [G:A][SG:B][Key:HL9703182570]

Now I need to fetch first single key from collection based on Key pattern - [G:A][SG:B] which basically should fetch [G:A][SG:B][Key:HL9703182569] . Is there a way that I can fetch using Keys method without getting all the keys. I understand there is no order in Radis but can it return like FIFO?